# Android: Maps is not getting displayed

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried to add map activity in my android application. I generated the API key and without any error I have finished the coding but in my output I am not getting the map displayed only the grid lines are visible. Please help me to display the map or please help me with the codes. I have installed the respective Google libraries.

Comment: Please Enable MapAPi On Google Consaol

Comment: Check the Google Developers Console. Ensure maps are on and your credentials (with SHA1) are correctly setup.

Comment: Did you follow the step by step procedure from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually derived from a problem in referencing `google-play-service` library.
Take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to integrate Google Maps in your application, especially the first 3 steps:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

another cause of this could be that you haven't configured the Google API Console properly, so I suggest you to take a look at this guide as well:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

another reason that may cause this is if you have some kind of problem in your permissions in the manifest file. You can look at the first guide for the needed permissions as well.